# pushd not changing directory in php on ubuntu 14.04

Tags: php, linux, ubuntu-14.04

sorry i posted the wrong code before but this is the question again.

i'm trying to use pushd in an exec from php but the working directory doesn't change. I have got the sample code to a few lines:

```
<?php
    exec('pwd; pushd abc/def/; pwd; popd; pwd; 2>&1', $output);
    echo('<pre>');
    print_r($output);
```

the output is

```
Array
(
    [0] => /var/www/html
    [1] => /var/www/html
    [2] => /var/www/html
)
```

i would all like to thank you all in advance in an attempt to answer this question
vinaka

Comment: I don't see any pushd in the command, can you check again?

Comment: oops sorry i posted the wrong code

Answer (score 1):

Concerning your question:

exec() creates a new process, which has its own working directory, so it doesn't affect the working copy of the process that started it. Just type "change working directory php" into the starting page of your browser and do some research, that shouldn't be too difficult to find out.

Concerning your code:

Not every shell has a `pushd` builtin. For example, the default /bin/sh on Debian doesn't, but you don't see that because you only capture stdout, not stderr, in spite of your attempts. I'd suggest writing your code in PHP though instead of parsing shell output.

Answer (score 1):

If you would like to change the directory for the currently running PHP process, use

```
chdir ( $directory )
```

This returns true/false based on success/failure.

http://php.net/manual/en/function.chdir.php